# locks needed for multithreaded python scraping?

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x

I have a list of zipcodes that I want to pull business listings for using the yelp fusion api. Each zipcode will have to make at least one api call (  often much more) and so, I want to be able to keep track of my api usage as the daily limit is 25000. I have defined each zipcode as an instance of user defined Locale class. This locale class has a class variable Locale.pulls, which acts as a global counter for the number of pulls.

I want to multithread this using the multiprocessing module but I am not sure if I need to use locks and if so, how would I do so? The concern is race conditions as I need to be sure each thread sees the current number of pulls defined as the Zip.pulls class variable in the pseudo code below.

```
import multiprocessing.dummy as mt 


class Locale():
    pulls = 0
    MAX_PULLS = 20000

    def __init__(self,x,y):
        #initialize the instance with arguments needed to complete the API call  

    def pull(self):
        if Locale.pulls > MAX_PULLS: 
            return none
        else: 
            # make the request, store the returned data and increment the counter
            self.data = self.call_yelp() 
            Locale.pulls += 1


def main():
    #zipcodes below is a list of arguments needed to initialize each zipcode as a Locale class object
    pool = mt.Pool(len(zipcodes)/100) # let each thread work on 100 zipcodes
    data = pool.map(Locale, zipcodes)
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to check that `len(zipcodes) < MAP_PULLS` before running the `map()`.